# grasping uniform convergence for function series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I would like some help with my grasping the idea of uniformly convergence for a series of function.

I know that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)| = 0$ than the series $ {f_n(x)}$ converges uniformly, where $f(x)$ is the limit function.

If we look at the function $x^n$ when $0\le x\le1$ than:

$f(x)$ is $0$ when $0\le x\lt1$ and $1$ when $x=1$

on one hand, the function $f(x)$ is not continuous so I think it's safe to assume the function series is not uniform convergence. is that enough to answer the question?

on the second hand, when i tried to use the notation above I got different result when I look at the two situations separately.

when $0\le x\lt1$ than $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)| =0$

when $x=1$ than $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sup|f_n(1)-f(1)| =0$

how to use the notation above for that question?

Comment: What "different results" did you get? Can you please show what you did?

Comment: @uniquesolution I have edited as you requested but something in my thinking process is wrong.

Comment: What seems to be wrong is that you are trying to substitute $x$ into an expression which does not depend on $x$. You see, once you take the supremeum of $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ over ALL $x$'s in $[0,1]$ , you get a number depending only on $n$. Now try to compute this supremum for each $n$ and see what you get.

Comment: @uniquesolution can you please show me how? if I will see it once done right it will really help me

Comment: For $f_n(x)=x^n$ and your $f(x)$ you have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|x^n|$ if $x<1$ and $0$ otherwise. Therefore $\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|=1$ for every $n$. Therefore the limit is also $1$.

Comment: You use series of functions instead of SEQUENCE of functions.

Comment: Its important to note that a function need not always attain its supremum. In your case the supremum in both the cases is $1$. For $x=1$ it is clear that the supremum is $1$. Also, for $x \in [0,1)$ the supremum value is $1$, though this values is never attained by $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$.

Comment: @Naive that is what I was missing. thank you for explaining that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uniquesolution's comments answer the question, but in the hope a picture helps:

[image: Pointwise and uniform convergence of a function sequence]

You're correct that if a sequence $(f_{n})$ of continuous functions converges to a discontinuous limit $f$, the convergence is not uniform.

Note carefully, however, that discontinuity of the limit is not necessary; a sequence of continuous functions can converge non-uniformly to a continuous limit. For example:

- If $f_{n}(x) = x^{n}$ for $0 \leq x < 1$, then $(f_{n}) \to 0$ pointwise, but the convergence is not uniform. (As the animation loop indicates, if $0 < a < 1$ is fixed, the convergence *is* uniform on $[0, a]$.)
- If $f_{n}(x) = x/n$ for $0 \leq x$, then $(f_{n}) \to 0$, but the convergence is not uniform.

(I leave to you the fun of finding a sequence of continuous functions $(f_{n})$ that converge pointwise to the continuous function $0$ on the compact set $[0, 1]$, but the convergence is not uniform.)

Comment: The animation is amazing. Might I ask you how did you make it?

Comment: Good JOB. God bless you.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I used [ePiX](http://mathcs.holycross.edu/~ahwang/epix/ePiX.html) (whose documentation, to be honest, really needs to be re-written...).

Comment: thank you so much! I understand that now :)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: Thank you!

Comment: Should your last bullet point have ​ $x\hspace{.02 in}/n$ ​ instead of ​ $nx$ ? ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Oops, yes...thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The third line from bottom is false.

$$\sup_{[0,1)}|x^n|=1$$